# .toml stream did not contain valid UTF-8

Tags: parity, configuration

While trying to configure parity using the toml file ([Tom's Obvious, Minimal Language](https://github.com/toml-lang/toml)), I stumbled on this error -

```
$ parity --config /data/parity/node.toml
Loading config file from /data/parity/node.toml
There was an error reading your config file at: /data/parity/node.toml
stream did not contain valid UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0):

Upon close inspection, the problem was with the IDE.
I used Sublime Text to edit and save the .toml file
Despite adding `"string-name"` in order to indicate a string, somehow when I verified by reopening the file using `vim node.toml` I could see \095 instead of " which indicates that it didn't catch the `""` properly. So I edited the file in vim editor and it resolved my issue.